# What is UFW's approach towards rules order for overlapping rules?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I need to enable UFW in my Ubuntu 14.04 Server having these conditions:

- I want to deny all incoming and outgoing on all ports (and protocols) but:

- I want to allow all incoming and outgoing on a port.

- I want to deny a specific ip from anything.

I do this:

ufw default deny

ufw allow {port}

ufw deny from {ip}

Now, my question is "**did I do it right?**" Or more general "**What is UFW's approach towards rules order for overlapping rules?**"
Thanks